# Mongo: Alternative to bidrectional relationship?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, schema, hierarchy, database

I have a set up like:

```
Collection 1
    Document A
        _id= asdf
        doc_B = ObjectId(qwer)

Collection 2
    Document B
        _id= qwer
        doc_A = OvjectId(asdf)
```

I understand the concept of bidirectional relationships via reference but I was thinking; If the documents that are being related are on different collections, why can't I just set both Doc A and B OID to the same value?

```
Collection 1
    Document A
        _id= wasd

Collection 2
    Document B
        _id= wasd
```

Is this schema a bad idea?

Comment: if by OID you mean objectId then sure you can do that, in fact many do

Comment: yes, by oid I mean the autogenerated _id: field in mongo. So having duplicate objectID's in different collections won't blow up in my face down the line?

Comment: Nah, it will be fine